# Как зайти на ChatGPT?

Tags: искусственный-интеллект

Я один уже 3 дня не могу зайти на ChatGPT? VPN работает, но нагрузка на сервис всегда очень большая. Скажите может кто знает, какие-нибудь другие способы, чтобы на него зайти или другие ИИ для программистов?

Answer (score 3):

- https://you.com - есть вклада чат, сделан наподобие chatgpt, там диалога не больше 2-3х вопросов получиться задать из-за ограничений, но зато умеет код писать...
- https://phind.com/
- https://www.perplexity.ai/ - крутой сайт, отвечает на русском, и показывает еще связанные темы с вопросом
- https://useadrenaline.com/ — нейросеть исправит ваш код

очень много инструментов для помощи написания кода:

- https://share-docs.clickup.com/25598832/d/h/rd6vg-14247/0b79ca1dc0f7429/rd6vg-12585

Answer (score 1):

Ждать пока на аккаунте появится кнопка "Upgrade to Plus" и оплатить подписку, что позволит получать доступ к сервису даже во время пиковых нагрузок. Других способов нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]